# Recargar componente al cambiar la resolucion vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, buefy

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola, estoy usando el componente "carousel" de Buefy con Vue.js.
En resolucion de laptop tengo que se muestren 3 items.
Pero en el movil quiero que se muestre un item.
hice una funcion que depende de la resolucion se cambie la propiedad del carousel "items-to-show" de 3 a 1.
Pero lo malo que esa propiedad se carga cuando se inicia la pagina no cuando cambia la pantalla.

Tienen algun consejo de como hacerlo ? No quiero tener que recargar la pagina para que suceda. Pero al menos recargar el componente.

```
<section id="app">
<h1 class="title is-1">{{ titulo }}</h1>
<p class="subtitle is-5">{{ subtitulo }}</p>
<div class="container"  id="id">
<b-carousel-list v-model="test" :data="items" :items-to-show="valor" :items-to-list="3" icon-size="is-large">
    <template slot="item" slot-scope="props">
        <div class="card redondo">
            <div class="card-image">
                <figure class="image is-5by4">
                     <a @click="info(props.index)"><img :src="props.list.image" class="imagen-redondo"></a>
                </figure>
            </div>
               <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="container">
                    <h3 class="Laboratorio-Centro" >{{ props.list.title }}</h3>
                    <div class="columns is-mobile">
                    <div class="column is-1 ">
                        <figure class="image is-16x16">
                        <img src="../assets/img/location.png">
                        </figure>

                    </div>
                    <div class="column">
                         <p class="Av-9-de-Octubre-170">{{ props.list.subtitle}}</p>

                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="boton-plus2"> <img src="../assets/img/icon-more.png" @click="isCardModalActive = true" class="plus2">
                                    
            </div>
    
      
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
                        
    </template>
        </b-carousel-list>
</div>


</section>    
methods: {
            info(value) {
                this.test = value

            },
            cambiar() {

                return this.test = 0;
            },
            itemMostrar() {
                if ($(window).width() < 720) {
                    return this.valor = 1;
                } else {

                    return this.valor = 3;
                }
            },
      
        },
```

Comment: Y no sería más sencillo maquetar eso con media queries?, Me parece demasiado darle esa tarea a JS

Comment: Pero es que necesito cambiarle el valor a una propiedad de un componente de Buefy. :items-to-show="valor".

Comment: Con SCSS me recargaria el ese valor y lo llevaria al carousel?

Answer (score 1):

Para esto puedes usar `window.matchMedia`

```
var mql = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 700px)');

mql.addListener(function (event) {
  if (event.matches) { // La media querie coincide
    this.valor = 1;
  } else {
    this.valor = 3;
  }
});
```

Esto podrías añadirlo en el `mounted()`

**Para más info:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener